# logstash input plugin for postgresql db- duplication (ignoring last run state)

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using jdbc plugin to fetch data from postgresql db, it works  for entire export and i am able to pull the data, but it is not working according to saved state, everytime all of data is queried and there are lot of duplicates.

```
input 
{
jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:5432/dodb"
jdbc_user => "myuser"
jdbc_password => "passsword"
jdbc_validate_connection => true
jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/postgresql-9.4.1207.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
statement => "select id,timestamp,distributed_query_id,distributed_query_task_id, "columns"->>'uid' as uid, "columns"->>'name' as name from distributed_query_result;"
schedule => "* * * * *"
use_column_value => true
tracking_column => "id"
tracking_column_type => "numeric"
clean_run => true
}
}
output
{
kafka{
topic_id => "psql-logs"
bootstrap_servers => "x.x.x.x:9092"
codec => "json"
}
}
```

I checked the .logstash_jdbc_last_run. The metadata state is updated as required, still plugin is importing entire data from table on every run.

Any help !! Thanks in advnce

Comment: Solved, have to add sql_last_value at end of query

Comment: where id>:sql_last_value             (id is column name in my table)